# Can I have a line of code as a variable and apply this line of code if it exist?

Tags: javascript

Can I carry a line-of-code in an object - and run the code if it exists? For instance- an array carries info applied to inbound messages for further processing. The topic is used to retrieve the right info to do calculations etc with. If the topic is the same as the 2nd object - I want to retrieve the line of code in the post-processing - and do further data manipulation with such a line.

Is this possible? What would such the JS look like to execute the line of code in the variable `postProcessing` ?

```
[{"topic":"com.victronenergy.vebus.ttyS3 - /Soc","outValDec":0,"attrUnit":"%","unique_id":"batterySoc","svgDash":1,"hass_component":"battery"},

{"topic":"com.victronenergy.vebus.ttyS3 - /Ac/Out/L1/P","outValDec":0,"attrUnit":"W","unique_id":"acloads_W","svgDash":1,"hass_component":"power"},{"topic":"com.victronenergy.vebus.ttyS3 - /State","outValDec":0,"attrUnit":"","unique_id":"SystemStateDesc","svgDash":1,"hass_component":"sensor","postProcessing":"outVal = (global.get('cfgLists','storeInFile').victronState)[outVal].desc"}]
```

Comment: Can you? Yes, definitely. At the end of the day, the JavaScript code you type in a file is just a string, after all. Should you? Maybe, maybe not. Running arbitrary code submitted in a string is full of security risks.

Comment: You can with `eval`. But there are obviously security issues to consider. What's the source of these objects/those code lines?

Comment: I carry the object inside Node-RED - so low chance of injection. Thank you, I now recall that this is possible, and the associated risks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I carry a line-of-code in an object - and run the code if it exists?

Yes, definitely. At the end of the day, the JavaScript code you type in a file is just a string that the computer parses and evaluates. This is how all computer languages work.

Should you, though? Maybe, maybe not. Running arbitrary code submitted in a string is full of security risks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` function. Just pass it a string. But it is not recommended.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, have used it before - forgot about it. Gonna try it now.